# Chrome Extension Not Stopping

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am encountering a problem on Google Chrome. There are multiple chrome tasks running in the windows task manager, and when I look at the chrome task manager, there is an extension that consumes a lot of energy. When I kill it, it reappears. The extension has no name (written as 'Extension: '), and since it doesn't close I'm not even able to reinstall the software. I have also tried removing ALL extensions, it still reappears.
Kindly do help since it's slowing Chrome down.